# how to use stdscr.addstr() (curses) to print unicode characters

Tags: python-2.7

I know how to use the print() function to print unicode characters, but I do not know how to do it using stdscr.addstr()

I'm using python 2.7 on a Linux operating system

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure you need to encode the string. 
The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) reads:

> Since version 5.4, the ncurses library decides how to interpret non-ASCII data using the nl_langinfo function. That means that you have to call locale.setlocale() in the application and encode Unicode strings using one of the system’s available encodings.

This example worked for me in 2.7.12

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, mystring.encode('UTF-8'))
```